# How can I retrieve the SQL table name in Slick 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-2.0

I need to have access to the SQL table name and since my Slick scheme already stores it, I would like to access it directly through the slick object without having to store it twice.

In Slick 1.0, this can be achieved with
`table.tableName`

assuming `table` is e.g.

```
class MyTable Table[MyCaseClass]("my_table_name") {
    def id              = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    ....

    def * = id.? ~ .... <> (MyCaseClass, MyCaseClass.unapply _)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I found in Slick 2.0 ...

`MyClass.query.baseTableRow.tableName`

where

```
class MyClass(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyCaseClass](tag, "table_name"){
    def id                  = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    ...


    def * = (id.? , ...) <> ((MyCaseClass.apply _).tupled, MyCaseClass.unapply)
 }
```